# Constructing a Generic object (not default constructor)

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I am wanting to construct an object from within a generic method. This object takes a `string` in its constructor. Something like this:

```
public T GetObject<T>()
{
    return new T("Hello");
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to rewrite this to force the caller to pass in a factory method / lambda

```
public T GetObject<T>(Func<string,T> func) 
{ 
  return func("Hello");
}
```

The call site would be modified to look like this

```
GetObject(x => new T(x));
```

Comment: The method signature gets a lot more complicated than dtb's solution, but I do like the compile-time checking that comes with it. Trade-offs, I guess.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, but only without compile-time checking if the constructor really exists: [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx)

```
public T GetObject<T>()
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), "Hello");
}
```

Comment: So if the `(string)` constructor doesn't exist, it'll be a runtime error?

Comment: @Smashery: Exactly. It will throw an exception if `T` doesn't have a public `(string)` constructor.

Comment: Thanks very much! Sucks I can only pick one "correct answer", but thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

No. At the moment you cannot use parameterised constructors with generic types since you cannot define them in where.

Using Activator is not the same - and I believe not the answer to your question - but you can use it of course.